# About the screen on in android application

Tags: java, android, screen

I have an Android application and I want to keep the screen on. But sometimes I don't want to keep the screen on. What can I do to that?

**EDIT:** I have already used this code to set my screen on:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: clear your flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need your application not to keep screen on, you can clear the `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag using this code:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is the simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs - either

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

in layout or programatically

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I guess you are looking for this. You can do this grammatically.

[Keep Screen Awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

or Add this to your layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user8119433 so you can add a condition and do the same. But you will have to navigate back or refresh the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Find the root layout of the activity. for example if the root layout is a *LinearLayout*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xml);
    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_container):

    // and according to your preference you can set 
    root.setKeepScreenOn(true/false);
```

offical doc says

```
 /**
 * Controls whether the screen should remain on, modifying the
 * value of {@link #KEEP_SCREEN_ON}.
 *
 * @param keepScreenOn Supply true to set {@link #KEEP_SCREEN_ON}.
 *
 * @see #getKeepScreenOn()

 */
```

For more reference please follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) link

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and then :

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Hope this helps.